# Подсвечивание элементов

Tags: eclipse, java

Добрый день всем!
Раньше при работе с IDE Eclipse, при нажатии на элемент, например переменную, она подсвечивалась везде, где использовалась. Как включить эту функцию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В контекстном меню редактора кода выбираете `Preferences...`

В дереве настроек `Java`→`Editor`→`Mark Occurences`.

В редакторе выбираете то, что Вам надо подсвечивать.

Comment: Если не нужно настраивать, а просто Вкл/выкл:      
 Alt+Shift+O или кнопка в тулбаре "Toggle Mark Occurrences"